# Adding a ISO week number column to a dataframe removes the results of other added columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have made a dataframe that looks something like this

| StockID | IN Date | Inspection Date | PHOTO Date | Sales Date | Invoiced Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 04/10/2021 |  |  |  |  |
| 102 | 09/09/2021 | 14/09/2021 |  | 13/09/2021 |  |
| 103 | 02/09/2021 | 27/10/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 02/10/2021 | 06/10/2021 |

I want to add new columns so I did this

```
try:
    TimeETA['In to Photo'] = TimeETA['PHOTO Date'] - TimeETA['IN Date']
    TimeETA['In to Insp'] = TimeETA['Inspection Date'] - TimeETA['IN Date']
    TimeETA['Insp to Photo'] = TimeETA['PHOTO Date'] - TimeETA['Inspection Date']
    TimeETA['Sold to Photo'] = TimeETA['PHOTO Date'] - TimeETA['Sales Date']
    TimeETA['In to Sold'] = TimeETA['Sales Date'] - TimeETA['IN Date']
    TimeETA['In to Invoice'] = TimeETA['Invoiced Date'] - TimeETA['IN Date']
    TimeETA['Sold to Invoice'] = TimeETA['Invoiced Date'] - TimeETA['Sales Date']
except:
    TimeETA['In to Photo'] = ''
    TimeETA['In to Insp'] = ''
    TimeETA['Insp to Photo'] = ''
    TimeETA['Sold to Photo'] = ''
    TimeETA['In to Sold'] = ''
    TimeETA['In to Invoice'] = ''
    TimeETA['Sold to Invoice'] = ''
```

This worked and then I added a column for the ISO week number based on the 'In Date' column so I added the line blow to the try function

```
TimeETA['IN ISO'] = TimeETA['IN Date'].isocalendar()[1]
```

However it didn't work so instead I put that in a for loop like so

```
for i in range(len(TimeETA)):
    try:
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN ISO'] = TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN Date'].isocalendar()[1]
    except:
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN ISO'] = ''
```

which worked, now I wanted to add another 2 columns one for ISO week number based on the 'PHOTO date' and another the subtract todays date from the 'Sales Date', like so

```
today = date.today()    
for i in range(len(TimeETA)):
    try:
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN ISO'] = TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN Date'].isocalendar()[1]
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'PHOTO ISO'] = TimeETA.loc[i, 'PHOTO Date'].isocalendar()[1]
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'Sold WIP Days'] = today - TimeETA.loc[i, 'Sales Date']
    except:
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'IN ISO'] = ''
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'FullTT ISO'] = ''
        TimeETA.loc[i, 'Sold WIP Days'] = ''
```

However when I do that the results of all new columns are gone (they are empty). I am not sure why?

Comment: Please indicate the data format for the time fields in your dataframe.  Are they datetime stamps or string data?

Comment: All the dates are datetime stamps